# TypeError: item is null in EXTJS 4 when using tabpanel

Tags: extjs

I am newbie. I am working on EXTJS 4,need your help in solving this.

I am encountering an error

"TypeError: item is null 
item.on(ename, fn, scope, options);                ext-all-debug.js (line 13795)"

when clicking on the link, which calls the function doThis() and the tabpanel associated with function disappear. Below is the function for your reference.

```
function doThis()
{
    var xxtabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        renderTo : Ext.fly('content').update(""),
        autoHeight:true,
        id:'xxtabPanel',
        tabHeight:200,
        activeTab:0,
        items : [ {
            id:'tab1',
            itemId:'Tab1',
            frame:true,
            title : 'Tab one Details',
            items :item1    //FormPanel
        }, {
            id:'tab2',
            frame:true,
            itemId:'Tab2',
            title : 'Tab two Details',
            items:item2   //FormPanel
        }, {
            id:'tab3',
            frame:true,
            itemId:'Tab3',
            title : 'Tab three Details',
            items :item3   //FormPanel
        } ],
        listeners: {
            'tabchange': function(tp, p) {

                tp.doLayout();
            }
        }

    });}
```

Thanks in advance..Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Where do you try to render the tab panel? Here is your example: http://jsfiddle.net/weghT/5/